# React-native when running an android project throws an error (null is not an object)

Tags: android, react-native

When I run my react-native project in the android emulator. It brings up an error.

Error message:

```
TypeError : null is not an object 
(evuluating '_RNGestureHAndlerModule.default.Direction')
```

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2x9n.png)

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your app tries to access an object that is null. Please add the relevant code to your question that others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The error screen you posted is of no use, try to use react native debugger or chrome devtools to know exact cause. this problem occurs when some property is being accessed before being initialized, or maybe null checking is absent from logic.

for debugging, open developer options using cmd+D in ios simulator, or cmd+M in android emulator. Choose debug JS remotely on port 8081.